# Does an ical file have to have an enddate?

Tags: php, icalendar

I'm currently writing a .ics file with php. I wonder if a `VEVENT` always needs to have an enddate?

Like … is this allowed?

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:d3f760e29fa3f482199f8ed0663d5cf7@mydomain.com
DTSTAMP:20130308T140833Z
DTSTART:20130404T053000Z
DTEND:
SUMMARY:Title of the entry
DESCRIPTION:Something something something …
END:VEVENT
```

or this …

```
 BEGIN:VEVENT
 UID:d3f760e29fa3f482199f8ed0663d5cf7@mydomain.com
 DTSTAMP:20130308T140833Z
 DTSTART:20130404T053000Z
 SUMMARY:Title of the entry
 DESCRIPTION:Something something something …
 END:VEVENT
```

Thank you for your help and tips.

*I simply ask this because there are events with an open end where I don't know when to set an enddate?*

Comment: Go straight to the definitive answer: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545

Comment: Quite a lot of text. Any reference you could give me?

Comment: @matt How about you just CTRL+F for `end date`?

Comment: @matt: that is **THE** reference. it's the official spec for the ical format.

Comment: Thank you: So did I get this right when saying if no enddate is specified the value should be set to `DTEND:STANDARD`. I'm having quite a few problem understanding specs like that.

Comment: @matt so what did you end up using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the more precise part of the spec is: [3.6.1.  Event Component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1) which states

> For cases where a "VEVENT" calendar component specifies a "DTSTART" property with a DATE value type but no "DTEND" nor "DURATION" property, the event's duration is taken to be one day.  For cases where a "VEVENT" calendar component specifies a "DTSTART" property with a DATE-TIME value type but no "DTEND" property, the event ends on the same calendar date and time of day specified by the "DTSTART" property.

in your case when you want an event starting now and with no end in sight, there is no provision in the spec.

Comment: as a delayed reaction, one possible alternative would be to have the event defined as a recurring event and then the RRULE could be running for ever: `RRULE:FREQ=DAILY`